# what is quick formatting in veracrypt?

Tags: veracrypt

In veracrypt, I'm going through all the options and attempting to understand them, and I have come to something called "quick formatting". In the volume creation wizard there is an option for "quick formatting". What is "quick formatting" and what does it do? Is there a contrasting "long formatting" if so, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the benefits of a full format versus a quick format when encrypting an external hard drive?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/200218/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-full-format-versus-a-quick-format-when-encrypting-an)

Comment: kinda, it lists the pro's and con's but it doesn't exactly say what one is vs the other, and i would like to UNDERSTAND what one and the other is, then understand the pro's and con's, that's what i would like anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Basically the gist is that quick format will not write to all the blocks on the drive (or in the container). That means:

1. remnants of previous data will remain visible until overwritten and
2. it will make it quite evident - based on entropy - that something is going on in the blocks that have been written to versus those that remain as before

Point 2 is what [the answer linked from a comment to your question](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/200220/1609) is talking about. The fact that only the locations on the drive that are occupied by metadata will be overwritten by a *quick* format operation means that you can *guess* by looking at the entropy
of the blocks whether they contain encrypted data or plain text.

Generally in cryptography it's seen as a weakness if any information about the encrypted message "leaks". This is why generally encryption systems will pad out the end of encrypted messages to the multiple of a given block size just to make sure the attacker cannot guess the *actual* length of the *actual* message.

That's why the recommendation is to do the full format. And I would also *recommend* that. Simply because by not doing the full format, you are weakening the initial state of the encrypted volume. This will go away over time as the volume fills up. But exactly that information may be valuable to an attacker.

If *however*, you are looking for *plausible deniability*, then you **absolutely positively have to do a full format** because the entropy of the blocks will let an adversary make assumptions about the contents. Similarly a hidden volume will not be thinkable without doing a full format, because the idea of a hidden volume is to use an alternate key to show alternate data and so from the outside both regions (hidden and not hidden) should be indistinguishable for an attacker. Anything else will - again - weaken the effect of the crypto.

So don't be cheap when it comes to security.

**NB:** a nice side-effect is that going through this *once* enables you to do a "full wipe" instantaneously. The way this works (e.g. on some phones) is by throwing away the key material. So you're left with an encrypted volume which no one can make sense of anymore.

#### What's entropy?

[Entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(computing)) in computing is a measurement of the randomness of data. Generally extreme compression and encryption will have a relatively even distribution of byte values. Meaning they have both high entropy. Tools exist to map out the "jumps" in entropy (this is used in firmware analysis, for example) and these tools would show - in case of quick format - jumps between the locations on the disk that were written during the quick format operation and those that weren't touched.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation on it is also available at https://documentation.help/VeraCrypt/Creating%20New%20Volumes.html#QuickFormat

> If unchecked, each sector of the new volume will be formatted. This means that the new volume will be entirely filled with random data. Quick format is much faster but may be less secure because until the whole volume has been filled with files, it may be possible to tell how much data it contains (if the space was not filled with random data beforehand). If you are not sure whether to enable or disable Quick Format, we recommend that you leave this option unchecked. Note that Quick Format can only be enabled when encrypting partitions/devices.
>
> Important: When encrypting a partition/device within which you intend to create a hidden volume afterwards, leave this option unchecked.